# Select content under div css

Tags: html, css

I have a transparent `<div>` that has a width and height of `100%` with content larger than itself so that it covers the entire screen and scrolls. I need to be able to select and hover over elements that are behind it. As can be seen by the example below, I am unable to do any of this. How do I fix this without removing the scrollable `<div>`?

```css
#screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: auto;
}

#content {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='screen'>
    <div id='content'></div>
</div>
<span>highlight me!</span>
<button>click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add  `pointer-events: none;` to the overlay `div#screen`:

```css
#screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='screen'></div>
<span>highlight me!</span>
<button>click me!</button>
```

That makes elements "click-through".

Comment: Sorry to edit my question - I didn't think this would be relevant, but the `#screen` div needs to scroll (see the updated question). Apparently `pointer-events: none;` prohibits that.

Comment: Ah sorry, I see now that I can put the `pointer-events` property in the `content` div.

Comment: Hard to scroll an element with `height: 100%;` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the div around the content;

```html
<div id='screen'>
<span>highlight me!</span>
<button>click me!</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: There's too many ways in which this does not address the problem and creates unwanted layout to even start explaining in a comment.

Comment: I see no problem nesting content in a container div, but am happy to hear your thoughts if you wish to elaborate.

Comment: Maybe you didn't spot that `div#screen` is designed to be a page overlay.

Comment: Indeed. I was thinking that the intended result was the div being a wrapper of sorts, which adjusting the closing tag would sort out. Thanks for pointing that out.